# Downgrade Android App Sdk

Tags: android, api, sdk, android-4.4-kitkat

So I have a phone with `Lollipop (5.0)` and want to make my app compatible with phones that have `KitKat(4.4)`. `Min Sdk Version: 19`. `Target Sdk version: API 21 (lollipop)`. `Build tools version: 21.1.2`. `Compile Sdk version: API 21`.

My question is:

What do I need to change so my app won't be affected?
I have downloaded everything about `API 19` in Sdk manager, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In your android manifest set your uses-sdk to the following values:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

So long as you aren't using any sdk 21 only functions or classes you should be good. Running a clean will show you warnings for any functions or class you are using that aren't supported by your min sdk

Comment: That worked. 
Just that my external libraries (Azure) do not seem to be compatible with Api 19 or something because i can send information to a Database with my main phone (Lollipop) and a friends phone with KitKat won't do the same. Thanks!